# how is it possible to return different responses of your server based on URL

Tags: java, url, jetty

Lets say we have two URLs which points to the same server, and now we want to tell users who use one of the URLs that it is no longer supported. What is the best way to do it?
We have jetty as an application server and our server code written in java.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect from the old one to the new one, with a `301 Moved Permanently` status code. That is the transparent, standard way of doing.

If you really want to tell users not to use it, then just do that: return a page with a message saying not to use this URL anymore, and add a link to the new URL in the page.

Comment: Jetty has a handler that can help with this as well if you like: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/moved-context-handler.html

Comment: can it be used to redirect the following path for example: from [http://www.kuku.com/bubu] to [http://www.kuku123.com/bubu]?

Comment: Of course it can. Why couldn't it? You can redirect to whatever URL you like. A redirect just says to the browser: "nothing to see here, execute a new GET request to the following location".

Comment: I still have this problem. i would like to redirect from: 'www.abc.com/*' to 'www.efg.com/*'. I try to play with 'MovedContextHandler' with contextPath variable but it seems it can't get a path parameter but only a part of the path such as if the path is: 'www.abc.com/kuku' that the part would be: '/kuku'.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to redirect when used URL was pointing to some soon to be disabled server name. For example we have www.kuku.com/blabla and now we changed it to www.shmuku.com/blabla, but for all the users who bookmarked kuku server we would like to tell them to replace their bookmark. So the solution was to implement additional servlet filter and there to check which server is in the request. In case it is kuku, simply create HTML response explaining to replace to new server URL.